# How would I use 'Last' command in bash to see who logged in the last 30 seconds?

Tags: bash, unix

'last' time walls (from time A to B) seem to only measure in days. Example, if I wanted to see who logged into a server in the last day, I would write

```
last -b 0 -t 1
```

If I wanted to, say, find out who logged in the last 30 seconds... How would I change those time walls? Is 'last' capable of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

from `man last`:

```
-t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
Display the state of logins as of the specified time. This is useful, e.g., to 
determine easily who was logged in at a particular time -- specify that time with -t 
and look for "still logged in".
```

Easiest way: grab the list of who was logged in 30 seconds ago, and grab the list of people who are logged in now. Find the people on the new list who aren't on the old list.

TL;DR: Yes, `last` can do this.

Comment: How do I only list users that are still logged in?

Comment: `last -t 20190220110107 | grep "still logged in" | cut -f1 -d' '`